# Change the column values in pandas based on conditions from two or more columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace column 'k' based on conditions from two columns, and found this code snippet on github..

This is the code snippet:

```
df.loc[(df['column1'] == some_value) & (df['column2'] == some_other_value), ['column_to_change']] = new_value
```

This is the code I use:

```
def merged_algo_A(cluster_array): 

    rows,labels = readCluster(cluster_array) # reading the test data

    xtest = pd.DataFrame(np.array(rows).reshape(len(rows),11), columns = list("abcdefghijk"))
    ytest = pd.DataFrame(np.array(labels).reshape(len(labels),1),columns = list("l"))

    #print(xtrain['c'])
    xtest['SportYes'] = np.where(xtest['c']<=16897, '200', '400')
    xtest['stateYes'] = np.where(xtest['k']<=62, '200', '400')
    xtest['durYes'] = np.where(xtest['a']<=0.0585, '200', '400')

    xtest.loc[(xtest['SportYes'] == 200) & (xtest['stateYes'] == 200), 'k'] = 3
    print(xtest)
```

Comment: Have you tried `xtest.loc[(xtest['SportYes'] == 200) & (xtest['stateYes'] == 200), 'k'] = 3` ?

Comment: Yes I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: Look at jpp code again ,there no [] for columns

Comment: Then please provide some data. See [mcve] for details.

Comment: there should be problem columns are non numeric, so need `xtest.loc[(xtest['SportYes'] == '200') & (xtest['stateYes'] == '200'), 'k'] = 3`, but without data hard to know. But help check it by `print(df.dtypes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `'200'` and `'400'` in `np.where` change to `200` and `400` for integers:

```
xtest['SportYes'] = np.where(xtest['c']<=16897, 200, 400)
xtest['stateYes'] = np.where(xtest['k']<=62, 200, 400)
xtest['durYes'] = np.where(xtest['a']<=0.0585, 200, 400)

xtest.loc[(xtest['SportYes'] == 200) & (xtest['stateYes'] == 200), 'k'] = 3
print(xtest)
```

Or add `''` to `200` and `400` in `loc` statement for compare by `string`s:

```
xtest['SportYes'] = np.where(xtest['c']<=16897, '200', '400')
xtest['stateYes'] = np.where(xtest['k']<=62, '200', '400')
xtest['durYes'] = np.where(xtest['a']<=0.0585, '200', '400')

xtest.loc[(xtest['SportYes'] == '200') & (xtest['stateYes'] == '200'), 'k'] = 3
print(xtest)
```

Comment: This didn't work. I even checked the data instances to make sure values satisfying these conditions do exist. I am curious about solving it :(

Comment: @Ara - What means it did not work? There are not 3 values in `k` column per rows with `SportYes=200` and `stateYes=200` ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved, The following is the code that solves it:

```
def merged_algo_A(cluster_array): 

    rows,labels = readCluster(cluster_array) # reading the test data

    xtest = pd.DataFrame(np.array(rows).reshape(len(rows),11), columns = list("abcdefghijk"))
    ytest = pd.DataFrame(np.array(labels).reshape(len(labels),1),columns = list("l"))


    xtest['SportYes'] = np.where(xtest['c']<=16897, 'yes', 'no')
    xtest['stateYes'] = np.where(xtest['f']<=62, 'yes', 'no')


    xtest['labels1'] = xtest['j']
    xtest['reallabels'] = ytest

    xtest.loc[(xtest['SportYes'] == 'yes') , ['labels1']] = 3
    xtest.loc[(xtest['SportYes'] == 'no')  , ['labels1']] = 2

    list1 = list(map(int,xtest['labels1']))

    final_preds = list1
    return final_preds
```